# How do you get the wildcard auto id parent of a document snapshot firestore onCreate function?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have looked at similar answers to similar questions but the answers don't specifically apply.
I am seeking the simple document parent auto-id in a firestore onCreate function in js?

The firestore function log reads function returned undefined for documentiD
How do you reference the documentID ?

Firestore Log result   :sendMailtransaction Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

```
//Send the transaction email
exports.sendMailtransaction = functions.firestore
    .document('Companys/{companyid}/Transaction/{transactionid}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const transDocument = functions.firestore.document('Companys/{companyid}/Transaction/{transactionid}');
        const documentiD = transDocument.documentID;


        const mailOptions = {
            from: 'L App<report@sample.com>',  // You can write any mail Address you want this doesn't effect anything,
            to: snap.data().companyemailcf, // This mail address should be filled with any mail you want to read it,
            bcc: 'admin@l.com',
            subject: 'L Record, New Tranaction ',
            html: `<h1>Confirmed Transaction</h1>
                                    <p>
                                       <b>Ref: </b>${documentiD}<br>
                                       <b>Datetime: </b>${snap.data().datetime}<br>
                                       <b>User: </b>${snap.data().user}<br>
                                       <b>Vehicle: </b>${snap.data().vehicle}<br>
                                       
                                    </p>`
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to query the created document to receive it in a function as you already have the document in the onCreate parameters: `snapshot` is the first parameter.

Example:

```
export const eventCreated = functions.firestore
    .document('/events/{eventId}')
    .onCreate(snapshot => {
        console.log("this is the new document id: ", snapshot.id)
        console.log("Document content:", snapshot.data())
    })
```

In your case, use `snap.id`

Firebase Functions guide is [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events)
The snapshots reference is explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot?hl=en)